# Creating a c# factory

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory

So I'm not sure if this is a legit factory or not. Most factory's I see have something like this in the client:

```
if(//something)
    factory = new Type1Factory();
else
    factory = new RegularFactory();
```

And then they create the object by going like `factory.Create();`

So basically the condition to check for which factory you want is right in the calling code. I'd prefer to hide that and have the condition in the factory itself, which I guess wouldn't be called a factory anymore?

Something like this:

```
DateScheduleRequest request = new DateScheduleRequest();
DateScheduleBuilder dateScheduleBuilder = new DateScheduleBuilderFactory(request).Create();
```

And the `dateScheduleBuilder` object would basically be of a certain type depending on the request sent to the factory constructor.

Is there another pattern for this or is this just a certain way to do factories?

Basically, `DateScheduleBuilder` would be a parent class that a bunch of other types of builders inherit from, but my calling code knows that this abstract class has one method, and it doesn't need to be aware of the request type, just the fact that it needs to pass it to the factory and call one method.

Comment: This sounds perfectly fine, and is a perfectly legitimate factory according to the GoF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are describing the factory pattern in the second part. The first part is not since it relies on the caller to know how to build the desired object. 
In your example, the `DateScheduleBuilderFactory` would be able to know how to interpret the information in the `request` object and return an object that derives from `DateScheduleBuilder`.

In short, like Johm Dom said above. You're already there...

Comment: Yes.  In my reading, @slandau thinks that if `DateScheduleBuilder dateScheduleBuilder` is not exactly of that basetype `DateScheduleBuilder`, then it doesn't count.  But it does.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the first snippet is perfectly fine. I would rather spend my time add features, fixing bugs than refactoring this.

If I were designing this code from scratch I would hide the `if` e.g. in constructor. A good rule of thumb: "Whenever library can do something easily for the consumer it should do it".

A third option is to move the if statement to vtable - polymorphism.

Comment: I like the hide IF in constructor and using Polymorphism behaviour to easier life.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is ok.

An alternative would be to have a factory factory.  So you have a class which has a method which gets a factory implementation based on the request (something like `IDateScheduleBuilderFactory GetDateSceduleBuilderFactory(request)` and then the consumer calls `Create()` on the `IDateScheduleBuilderFactory` to get the builder object.

Its slightly more convoluted but would mean you have a single classes with single responsibilities (ie one class whose job is to turn a request into the correct type of factory, and other classes to be the actual different types of factory) and you would be able to test this more easily.  How are you going to test that the correct type of factory is used given a particular request now?  You would have to determine this by the result of create, rather then just checking the type returned by the  `GetDateSceduleBuilderFactory()` method.

You could also have your current factories expose a method like `public bool CanHandleRequest(request)` which would allow each factory to decide if it was the correct factory for a particular request, then the factory factory could accept a collection of factories in its constructor and when the `GetDateSceduleBuilderFactory(request)` method was called it could loop round all of the factories asking each one if it can handle the request and when it finds one that can it returns it.

This has the advantage that you then don't need to change any logic when you add new factories, you can just have  some code which either gets all factories which implement the interface by reflection and then when you add new factories they will automatically get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it is not a factory, as it doesn't use the type to decide which object to create, but it is such a common (and useful) idiom that the Head First Design Patterns book calls it a Simple Factory.

It's perfectly legitimate in my view, and very useful (eg if creating strategies) in the right place,